How to handle API responses larger than 160 MB in Azure Logic Apps?
I'm using Azure Logic Apps to make a POST request to an API endpoint that returns a very large response (over 160 MB). When trying to handle this response, I encounter the following error:

Cannot write more bytes to the buffer than the configured maximum buffer size: 104857600

I've tried enabling the Allow chunking option in the Logic App's network settings and set the chunk size. However, I noticed that even when setting the chunk size to the maximum (49 MB), I still get the same error.

How can I correctly handle large API responses in Azure Logic Apps, considering the maximum buffer size limit of 100 MB?

If there is an alternative configuration or a better strategy to avoid this error, could you provide an example?


